# Creating a variable based on ID in Excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the following data:

```
id      Var1     Var2    outcome
1                          2
1                          2
1       12         6       1
2                          0
2                          0
3                          0
3                          0
.        .         .         .
```

So within an  `id`  group, if any of the variables are missing, then the outcome would be  `0` . If the variables are not missing, then the outcome would be  `1`  for that  `id`  and  `2`   for the rest if the ids. If the variables are missing for all ids within a group, then the outcome would be  `0` .

How would you do this in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested if and COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>",C:C,"<>")=0,0,IF(AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),1,2))
```

[image]